# What happens to a Li-Pol battery L13D1P31 if it is left on a permanent charge?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery, charging, tablet, lenovo

I have an old tablet (Lenovo Tab 2 A7-30 and a L13D1P31 battery) that I want to use as a permanent display of some data like a weather forecast.

I would like to leave this tablet plugged in permanently. However, it will not turn on when the battery is removed.

I found many articles on tablet operation without a battery, however, there were simple ones considered, and my battery is able to somehow communicate with the tablet.

- Can I not suffer and leave the battery in the tablet (or it just needs to be withdrawn)?
- Will there be overheating and fires?
- Will a battery operating in this mode be able to prevent an emergency shutdown of the tablet when the charger is powered off (so as not to damage the data in the flash memory)?
- Does the battery degrade so much that the tablet stops seeing it and won't turn on even when charging (even with the charger connected and the battery inserted, the tablet will not turn on)?

*UPD*: Tablet have a OEM battery. But for its intended purpose, this tablet is no longer needed, since there is a newer one. However, the old tablet keeps charging up to 4 days in passive mode (works as an alarm). It was bought 5 years ago.

Comment: Your tablet model is 7 years old and if you still are using the OEM battery, 1. It would be severely degraded as batteries do with age and performance and NOT a good idea to keep it on permanent charge as it would get heated up fast and *may* pose risks. 2. Change the battery if you can and use it normally

Comment: charger stop charging when battery is full, therefore i see no problem to leave it as is. furthermore some devices require battery for stable current and won't work without

Comment: Root your device and install an app that disables charging until e.g. battery reaches 40% (assuming such apps work on your device). Then you could limit charging between 40% and 60% which would to pose a risk to the battery anymore as charging in this region should be even for an old battery no problem.

Comment: @beeshyams Well, I do not need this tablet for its intended purpose ... I really would not want to buy a new battery. I would even like to run without the old one ..

Comment: @alecxs so what if the battery degrades so much that it will only give out picoamperes? Then, it turns out, the tablet will not turn on at all?

Comment: @Robert yes, I considered this option, but just ideally I would like to remove the battery... after all, it will still degrade, it will get hot when charging, etc.

Comment: @AlexA. If the battery is degraded really bad then the system may crash if the available current from charger + battery is too weak. Regarding the battery limited to 40-60% this should not be a problem as in that region charging does not produce much heat. As I said even old batteries should be able to handle charging in that region with nearly no degrading. Removing the battery is way more difficult. What may be possible is to strip the Li cells from the battery and leaver the "empty" battery in place. You may want to ask in an electronic forum about that option what they say.